# Jqgrid scroll issue with bindkeys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.4.1

The issue is when the grid has more data (more than a page) the vertical scroll bar displays, and when scroll down and select the last record the grid itself scrolls up and the selected record goes down(below the screen viewport) so I couldnt see the selected record.

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('bindKeys');
```

If I remove the scrollingRows it is not scrolling down when I press the down key to select the bottom records (so I need it to be true).

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('bindKeys', {'scrollingRows':false});
```

Help me on this to have bindkeys feature without record selection issue in my grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for this issue with the latest version of jqgrid(v 4.5.0).

in version 4.4.1

Line 2516:

```
.append($('<div style="'+(isMSIE && $.browser.version < 8 ? "height:0.01%;" : "")+'"></div>').append('<div></div>').append(this))
```

in version 4.5.0

Line 2731:

```
.append($('<div style="position:relative;'+(isMSIE && $.jgrid.msiever() < 8 ? "height:0.01%;" : "")+'"></div>').append('<div></div>').append(this))
```

I added the "position:relative;" to the style and solved the issue.

Thank you all.